# Why does the JS date act like this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have an array called dateArr which contains: [2014, 07, 10];

When I create a date out of it like below:

```
new Date(dateArr[0], Number(dateArr[1]), Number(dateArr[2]), 0, 0, 0);
```

It evaluates to '2014-08-09T23:00:00.000Z' in the console.
I understand thats months are zero based, but why, to correct the time, do I have to do this:

```
new Date(dateArr[0], Number(dateArr[1]) - 1, Number(dateArr[2]), 1, 0, 0);
```

Which gives: 2014-07-10T00:00:00.000Z

This doesn't seem right to me, could someone explain?

Comment: "I understand that months are zero based" There's your answer right there.

Comment: Question may not have been clear but look at the hours. if i leave out '1' it goes to 23:00, why?

Comment: This might be due to any daylight saving time?

Comment: It goes to Sun Aug 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) "without the 1" to me

Comment: Strange, in the chrome dev tools 'new Date(2014, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0)' evaluates to Thu Jul 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST), whereas in node, using webstorm, it evaluates to ‌‌‌2014-07-09T23:00:00.000Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tools are working with different timezones. (chrome dev tools output indicates that by adding GMT+0100(BST) to your output and therefore converting it to BST (British summer time) While webstorm gives you a utc/gmt time.
In fact 2014-07-09T23:00:00.000 is exactly the same time as Thu Jul 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST).

You may use `Date.UTC()` to generate a correct timestamp (but this will then be one hour off into the other direction in your local time)

I tried that within my own chrome developer console:

```
> new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0))
Thu Jul 10 2014 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (MESZ) //middle european summer time
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me,  out of interest, if querying mongodb through mongo, do you know if  they would take account of this?

Answer (score 2):

`new Date(2014, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0)` uses your current timezone (which is +0100 for you, and, e.g. +0400 for me in Moscow). So it's result will depends on timezone where you run the code.

```
> new Date(2014, 6, 10)
Thu Jul 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (MSK)
> new Date(2014, 6, 10).toISOString()
'2014-07-09T20:00:00.000Z'
```

if you really want midnight in «ISO time» you could use constructor with string:

```
> new Date('2014-06-10Z').toISOString()
'2014-06-10T00:00:00.000Z'
```

Comment: It just gives me the same result, as a string. new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0)) worked for me